# VBA - remove all rows until it finds requested value

Tags: vba, excel, find

could you advise me, what do I do wrong in the below code, please?

I have excel file with variable amount of data. The data sheet is splitted and I would need to remove the 2nd part of it. The 2nd part of data begins by "One or both Parties Not in Ico Loan Facility" in column A. So basically, I thought that I would start to find from behind and delete every row until it finds the cell contains the searching phrase, then it would stop.

The code removes everything until A3, even the 1st part of data. Do you have any advices, please?

```
Private Sub Remove_part2()

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Range

With Worksheets("Hyperion Data (Original)")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set r = Range("A3", "A" & Rows.Count).Find(What:="One or both Parties Not in Ico Loan Facility", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1

If Not r Is Nothing Then
  ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Private Sub Remove_part2()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Hyperion Data (Original)")

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = .Range("A3", "A" & .Rows.Count).Find(What:="One or both Parties Not in Ico Loan Facility", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        For i = LastRow To r.Row Step -1
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Criteria Not Found!", vbInformation
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Srpic glad I could help, hope it makes sense as you were nearly there. :)